# Can't remember the tech name of the opening scene of a game

Tags: terminology, technical

For example, when you play the game deadmaze, the first thing that shows up is a window filled with the login boxes, along with a background painting and other stuff. Does that generally have a specific tech name within the gaming context? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you thinking of the [Splash screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splash_screen)?

Comment: If there are "login boxes," then it's actually the login screen.

Answer (score 1):

The **splash screen** usually does not allow user interaction and serves only as an indicator that the game is launching. The **login screen** allows a user to log in. The **main menu** is usually a screen that allows the user to choose a game mode or level before beginning the real action of the game.

My hunch is that you are looking for **login screen**, because you specifically mention login boxes.